# Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative62DebugKotlin'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, kotlin, react-native-navigation

Getting this error my RNNKotlinVersion=0.6.0 and im running react-native-navigation version 6.7.0 , react-native version 0.63.0 and react version ^16.14.0

Tried updating kotlin version to 1.6.0 but no luck so far.
Is there any other way rather than updating versions

Comment: Can you please share the complete build log?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.